# How to programmatically interact with the UIToolbar that UINavigationController integrates by default?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, swift4

I'm researching about the **most optimal** way to interact with the UIToolbar that UINavigationController integrates by default.

I only wanted to **programmatically** add a static view at the bottom of my app and that's when I just realized UINavigationController has an UIToolbar already integrated.

**NOTE: All this without using Storyboard or Xib files.**

AppDelegate.swift:

```
...

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

   window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

   window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

   window?.rootViewController = MyNavigationController(rootViewController: MyTableViewController())

   return true

}

...
```

I show this code for you to understand **the approach** I've been follow so far.... and this is how my test application looks right now:

[image: Application example where you can see the UIToolbar (the blue segment) that comes integrated in UINavigationController by default.]

...the blue segment correspond to the UIToolbar I'm talking about, the one that UINavigationController integrates by default.

This UIToolbar could be **replaced with a custom implementation**? ...or maybe better would be to **interact directly** with this UIToolbar through my **custom** UINavigationController and **from there add all the subviews** I need?

Comment: Don't hack into `UIToolbar`, just put a static view under your `UINavigationController`.

Comment: Although I don't recommend to use a `UIToolbar` as a custom view, you could instantiate a `UINavigationColler` with you own custom toolbar subclass. `init(navigationBarClass: AnyClass?, toolbarClass: AnyClass?)`. But it's still a hack.

Answer (score 2):

I've chosen not to subclass UIToolbar, but instead I found more convenient (fast to implement) to interact directly with the "**toolbar**" property (a reference to the built-in toolbar) that comes **integrated by default** in UINavigationController.

I've read this toolbar is intended for client who wants to present an action sheet from the toolbar, also I shouldn't modify the UIToolbar object directly and the management of this toolbar’s contents is done through the custom view controllers associated with the navigation controller. (Apple words indeed.)

But in my particular case I don't need to show any action. I just want to use this toolbar to show information to the user, more like a status bar and eventually hide it at a particular view controller: something very easy to achieve with the boolean property **isToolbarHidden**.

Here's what I did: In my custom implementation of UITableViewController I added some UILabel that I directly add as subviews of the toolbar... with the **necessary** autolayout configuration.

MyTableViewController.swift:

```
import UIKit

class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController {

let monthlyLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

        label.sizeToFit()

        label.textAlignment = .left

        label.text = "Monthly:"

        return label

    }()

    let fixedMonthlyExpenses: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

        label.sizeToFit()

        label.textAlignment = .left

        return label

    }()

    let annuallyLabel: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 14)

        label.sizeToFit()

        label.textAlignment = .right

        label.text = "Annually:"

        return label

    }()

    let fixedAnnuallyExpenses: UILabel = {

        let label = UILabel()

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)

        label.sizeToFit()

        label.textAlignment = .right

        return label

    }()

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        navigationItem.title = "My Test"

        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 38/255, green: 38/255, blue: 38/255, alpha: 1)

        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()

        ...

        navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = false

        let monthlyLabel: NSNumber = 9.99
        let annuallyLabel: NSNumber = 119.88

        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()

        numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency

        fixedMonthlyExpenses.text = numberFormatter.string(from: monthlyLabel)
        fixedAnnuallyExpenses.text = numberFormatter.string(from: annuallyLabel)

        setupToolbarLayout()

    } // viewDidLoad

    ...

    func setupToolbarLayout() {

        guard let toolbar = navigationController?.toolbar else {

            return

        } // guard

        toolbar.addSubview(monthlyLabel)

        monthlyLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        monthlyLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        toolbar.addSubview(fixedMonthlyExpenses)

        fixedMonthlyExpenses.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: monthlyLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        fixedMonthlyExpenses.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        toolbar.addSubview(fixedAnnuallyExpenses)

        fixedAnnuallyExpenses.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.trailingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        fixedAnnuallyExpenses.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

        toolbar.addSubview(annuallyLabel)

        annuallyLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: fixedAnnuallyExpenses.leadingAnchor, constant: -5).isActive = true
        annuallyLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: toolbar.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    } // setupToolbarLayout

...

} // MyTableViewController
```

...and the application looks like:

[image: Shows an UIToolbar with some UILabel as subviews]

As you can see all this happens inside the setupToolbarLayout() function.

...so, yes it works! ...we can add subviews to the built-in toolbar reference that comes integrated within UINavigationController.